# Creating new folder when capturing images

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to create a new folder when I capture images and store it there. But my captured images is always going to my default gallery folder and the new folder is not appearing in the gallery if I don't restart my cellular phone. I need to restart my phone first for the folder to appear and the images captured to appear in that folder every time I take a pic.

```
Intent intent_cam = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

File imagesFolder = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Apps");

                if (!imagesFolder.exists()) {
                    imagesFolder.mkdirs();

                    File image = new File(imagesFolder, "Apps_" + timeStamp + ".png");
                    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);

                    intent_cam.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
                    startActivityForResult(intent_cam, 1);
                }
                else {
                    File image = new File(imagesFolder, "Apps_" + timeStamp + ".png");
                    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);

                    intent_cam.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
                    startActivityForResult(intent_cam, 1);
                }
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use folder creation condition like this.

```
if (!imagesFolder.exists() &&  imagesFolder.mkdirs())
```

> What is logcat saying???

Comment: Why do I need to put the imagesFolder.mkdirs() in the if statement?

Comment: To ensure that directory/folder is created. Function mkdirs() return true if it is successful.

Comment: if (!imagesFolder.exists()) { imagesFolder.mkdirs(); } ensures that the folder will be created successfully.

Comment: you are not checking mkdirs() return value.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my second problem about needing to restart using this line:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```